# Can I use the same button on multiple Android activities and return to original activity?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and making a very, very rough sketch of how my app will display information to users. I am making the app but not providing all the text it displays.

What I want to do is have multiple activities with a text box and underneath it have a button using the `oncreate` method (I believe the correct method) to have the exact same button on each activity linking back to main activity. What I want to do is make it so I don't have to recreate the intent or the button code on every page, just make a single line that does like "display button ID=home" on each activity. Just want to make it as simple as possible because I'll be making *a lot* of activities with text display.

When I figure it out I'm just going to drop the buttons and use a navigation drawer to access the info but need a draft for the team to start organizing the Information it displays.

I hope explaining what my final product will be can help show what I want to do. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create button programmatically.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Button button1 = createButton(this);
layout.addView(button1);

public static Button createButton(Activity a) { 
Button b = new Button(a);
    b.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(a.class.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    })
return b;
}
```